# SQLALCHEMY: There is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a relationship between my tables seller and item where each seller can sell any number of items but they can't sell the same item twice. Here's what I have:

```
sells = db.Table('sells',
     db.Column('seller_email', db.String(), db.ForeignKey('seller.email'), primary_key=True),
     db.Column('item_id', db.Integer, ForeignKey('item.id'), primary_key=True)
)

class Item(db.Model):
     __tablename__ = 'item'

     id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
     coverPhoto = db.Column(db.String())
     price = db.Column(db.Integer)
     condition = db.Column(db.Integer)
     title = db.Column(db.String())

     def __init__(self, title, coverPhoto, price, condition):
         self.coverPhoto = coverPhoto
         self.price = price
         self.condition = condition
         self.title = title

     def __repr__(self):
         return '<id {}>'.format(self.id)

class Seller(db.Model):
     __tablename__ = 'seller'

     email = db.Column(db.String(), primary_key=True)
     password = db.Column(db.String())
     firstName = db.Column(db.String())
     lastName = db.Column(db.String())
     location = db.Column(db.String())

     def __init__(self, email, password, firstName, lastName, location):
         self.email = email
         self.password = password
         self.firstName = firstName
         self.lastName = lastName
         self.location = location

     def __repr__(self):
         return "<Seller {email='%s'}>" % (self.email)
```

And I get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "seller"

[SQL: '\nCREATE TABLE sells (\n\tseller_email VARCHAR NOT NULL, \n\titem_id INTEGER NOT NULL, \n\tPRIMARY KEY (seller_email, item_id), \n\tFOREIGN KEY(item_id) REFERENCES item (id), \n\tFOREIGN KEY(seller_email) REFERENCES seller (email)\n)\n\n']
```

Bother seller.email and item.id are primary keys so shouldn't they inherently be unique?

Comment: Yes, primary keys are inherently unique.  I'm not knowledgeable about SQLAlchemy, but in an SQL database creation script, the definition of the relationship table would need to follow the definitions of the other two.  Does it make a difference if you move the `sells =` part to the end of your script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating the table `sells` using `db.Table`, a SQLAlchemy Core function. Nothing wrong with that. Then you create your other tables by inheriting from `db.Model` using the SQLAlchemy ORM's declarative syntax. (If you're not familiar with the difference between SQLAlchemy Core and ORM, the tutorial is a good place to start.)

You've got a couple of potential issues here:

1. You're using `db.Model` and the SQLAlchemy ORM's declarative syntax. When you do this, your model subclasses don't need an `__init__` function. In fact, using an `__init__` likely will cause problems (possibly even the root cause here) as it will interfere with the monkey-patching that SQLAlchemy does to make the Declarative syntax so convenient...
2. I suspect that the root cause here might actually be that you use SQLAlchemy Core to create a table with a foreign key reference to a SQLAlchemy ORM-managed table. Normally, when you do `db.metadata.create_all()`, SQLAlchemy will collect all the table/model mappings, look at the dependencies and figure out the correct ordering for emitting the `CREATE TABLE` / `ADD CONSTRAINT` commands to the database. This under-the-covers dependency resolving is what allows the app programmer to define a table that includes a foreign key to a table that is defined later. When you have a Core-based `Table` object that references a ORM `db.Model`-based object, it might prevent the dependency resolving from working correctly during table creation. I'm not 100% confident this is the issue, but it's worth experimenting with making all your tables either `Table` objects, or `db.Model` subclasses. If you're not sure, I'd suggest the latter.

Comment: http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/models/#many-to-many-relationships

Their documentation says otherwise. They suggest making the relation a table and everything else models.

Comment: It certainly can work, but it's a bit trickier to get everything configured correctly because you have to be more conscious of when you're using Core vs the ORM. Since you used an `__init__` in your model class, it looks like you're not that familiar with SQLAlchemy's declarative syntax, so that's partially why I suggested standardizing on one construct until you're comfortable with it. 

Did you try it without the `__init__` to see if that fixed the issue?

Comment: You're I'm not too familiar with SQLAlchemy. I followed this tutorial: https://realpython.com/blog/python/flask-by-example-part-2-postgres-sqlalchemy-and-alembic/ and they had `__init__` so I added it to mine as well. I actually got it working by copying the code from the link above.

Comment: See #1 here: http://alextechrants.blogspot.com/2013/11/10-common-stumbling-blocks-for.html

Comment: Thanks for taking your time and pointing me in the right direction. I think I've got it figured out.

Comment: So... was there a solution here or not?  If so, what exactly was it?  I see that this answer was accepted as correct but I don't see why.  The rest of us could use a hint before going down the same rabbit holes.

Comment: Well, anyway, turns out potential issues 1 and 2 were not issues for me. The Flask-SQLAlchemy method works just fine (although, yes, writing these `__init__`s does appear superfluous). For me, I just needed to create composite foreign keys to go with my composite primary keys and I got past this error. (BTW, that is done with `ForeignKeyConstraint` in `__table_args__`.) Using Alembic/Flask-Migrate to build the migration is probably what the OP needed.